# What to do if kill -9 doesn't work?

Tags: kill

I've got a pesky process (in this case, a stranded process that was supposed to be running in iPhone Simulator (now long quit).

```
97442 ??         0:00.00 (MyProcess)
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including

```
sudo kill -9 97442
sudo kill -HUP 97442
```

And yet, like the Raven... the process remains.

In this case, it means in order to continue working I have to reboot my machine.

Comment: Not a programming question - but have a look at zombie processes

Comment: Is there a better xxxOverflow then stackoverflow for this kind of question?

Comment: I voted for superuser- it should move automagically :-)

Comment: Shame is that the context is one that I keep seeing on X-Code 4 (Seems to happen while trying to debug in simulator) which means you can't continue working until you reboot, as trying to launch the app in the simulator with the zombie process in existence causes your app to crash immediately on launch.

Comment: Just trying to help here , take a look at this script , it helps me to kill any process with a given "name" works better than killall for me http://shellswissknife.blogspot.com/2013/03/killall.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a process remains in the process table as this process has, then you need to kill its *parent* process. First, find the parent process PID:

```
ps -eo 'pid,ppid,comm' | grep 97442
```

Then run `kill <pid>` for whatever the `ppid` result is. (Give it a chance to die cleanly, first.)

The traditional Unix design keeps process information around for the *parents* to reap and clean up, in case the parent processes want to run `getrusage(2)` to find out the resource usage of its children, or `wait(2)` for their exit status, etc.

When parents don't reap their children, the children remain zombies -- UNTIL the parent process is killed, at which point the kernel will re-parent the children to `init(8)`. `init(8)` *will* reap the newly re-parented children.

Comment: Hrm, sounds like it would be worth filing a bug report with Apple if you can get `launchd` to fail to reap a dead child. Will OS X restart `launchd` for you if you kill it? (Make certain you don't have any important unsaved content before testing.)

Comment: Hmm.. in this case the parent process is a launchd process, who's parent is PID 1 -- 

$ ps -eo 'ppid,comm' 97442
 PPID COMM
  155 (MyProcess)
$ ps -eo 'ppid,comm' 155
 PPID COMM
    1 /sbin/launchd
$ ps -eo 'ppid,comm' 1
 PPID COMM
    0 /sbin/launchd
$ ps -eo 'ppid,comm' 0
 PPID COMM

Comment: Yeah, tried sudo kill -HUP on the launchd process and didn't do anything, using the same rules, looked for it's parent and applied the same technique, still no joy.

Comment: I expect `launchd` will ignore or block the `HUP` signal. (Which signals a _modem hangup_. These days it's also used when `ssh` drops the connection, `bash(1)` or other shells will deliver `HUP` to the child processes it started. Because it can't happen for _daemons_, most daemons will either ignore it _or_ use it to signal a request to re-read a configuration file.) Try just `kill $(pidof launchd)` and if that fails, `kill -KILL $(pidof launchd)`.

Comment: You wouldn't need to kill `launchd`'s parent unless `launchd` was _also_ a zombie. But `launchd`'s parent is `init(8)`, and you probably cannot _kill_ `init(8)`. (At least the Linux kernel will only deliver signals to `init(8)` that it is explicitly prepared to handle. I suspect Darwin will do the same.) Even if `init(8)` did restart for you, your process would still remain unreaped by `launchd`, the task that is at fault here.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe this morphs into a launchctrl question... I tried killing the launchd process, but that took out my OS :)  Which ultimately allowed me to get back to work (after a restart)... however the mule in me seems to think there has to be a way to clear the process without necessitating a restart :/

Comment: @BadPirate, just let it be, zombie processes do not consume resources, apart from the tiny space it requires to be shown in the process table.

Comment: @sebleblanc -- I've found on stack overflow it's better to not assume you understand the detailed use case.  In this case, the zombie process was a branch of xcode simulator, and would prevent the xcode debugger from attaching correctly to the simulator.  Basically, xcode would bug creating the zombie, and then you wouldn't be able to continue to work until you rebooted the machine (yuck.).